# waitpid() not allowing SIGINT to be sent to child process?

Tags: c, unix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>


void sig_handler(int signal); 

int pid, forkFlag = 0;

int main( int argc, char **argv, char **envp )
{
  sigset(SIGINT, sig_handler); //handle ctrl + c
  sigignore(SIGTSTP);
  sigignore(SIGSTOP);

 int ex, rv, status;
        forkFlag = 1; //fork is being called

        pid = fork();

        if(pid == -1){

            perror("fork");
            exit(2);
        }
        else if (pid == 0){    //if child process

            ex = access(argv[0], X_OK);   //check if file is executable

            if(ex){

                perror("access");
                exit(1);
            }
            else{
                rv = execve(argv[0], argv, envp);  //run program in child process

                if(rv == -1){

                    perror("execve");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            exit(0);  //end child process
        }
        else{
            rv = waitpid(pid, &status, 0); //wait for child

            if(rv == -1){

                perror("waitpid");  
            }

            if(WEXITSTATUS(status)){   //check status of child if it did ot return 0

                printf("The return status of the child was %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
            }
        }
        forkFlag=0;
}

void sig_handler(int signal)
{
    if(signal == SIGINT && (pid && forkFlag)){

        kill(pid,signal); //send kill to child
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make my program ignore ctrl + C, except when there is a child process running, then it sends the the SIGINT to the child process. However, when I press ctrl + c when the child process is running, waitpid() returns -1 with the error "Interrupted System Call." This makes the child process stop running, but if I use ps, the child process is still there, but now labeled as defunct. I know from printf statements that kill is being calle din the function sig_handler, and that pid and forkFlag are their correct values. Is waitpid() making my program ignore the kill? How do I fix this? I know this code does next to nothing, but it's a small portion of my code (the only part involving fork)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the child processes get the same overridden handler for SIGINT. You probably want to reset the signal handler in the child process after the fork, or you might want to install the signal handler in the parent after you've already forked the child, so it doesn't inherit the overriden handler.

Comment: Is that really true?  I thought `execve()` resets the signal disposition for non-ignored signals in the child process.