# I/O redirection on Linux shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, io-redirection, dup2

Been working on a shell project. I have set up the I/O redirection, but I'm clearly missing something because when test it with a line like: "ls -al > outfile" it creates the outfile on my desktop, but leaves it empty and the program returns the following error:

```
ls: >: No such file or directory
Error: Failure to wait for child.
: Interrupted system call
```

Here is my code:

```
        pid_t child = fork();


        if (child < 0)
        {
            perror( "Error: Fork failure.\n" );
            exit(1);
        }

        else if (child == 0)
        {

            //If < file (read)
            if (inpt)
            {
                int fd_in = open(argumnts[index+1], O_RDONLY, 0);
                dup2(fd_in, STDIN_FILENO);
                close(fd_in);
                inpt = 0;
            }

            //If > file (create or truncate)
            if (outpt)
            {
                int fd_out_A = open(argumnts[index+1], O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666); 
                dup2(fd_out_A, STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(fd_out_A);
                outpt = 0;
            }


            execvp (argumnts[0], argumnts);

            perror(command);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            inpt = 0;
            outpt = 0;
            outptApp = 0;

            if ( waitpid(child, 0, WUNTRACED) < 0 )
                perror( "Error: Failure to wait for child.\n" );
        }
    }

} //End While(1) loop
```

The comparator function just checks to see if the command argument entered was "<", ">", or ">>", then returns the index where it is contained.

Not sure what I'm missing here, but it returs the errors mentioned before. Any idea?

Comment: You're leaving the redirection operator in the `arguments` array that you pass to `execvp()`. So `ls` is trying to list the file named `>`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the first error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate things going on.

1. `ls: >: No such file or directory` can be fixed by setting `argumnts[index]=NULL` before calling `execvp`.  `ls` is seeing the `> outputfile` as additional filenames it should list.  The `NULL` to terminate the argument list will take care of that.
2. `Error: Failure to wait for child. : Interrupted system call`: something is happening while waiting.  Interrupted system calls (`EINTR`) are often not a problem and can be restarted with no ill effects.  I found the following suggestion [here](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.programmer/2005-01/0347.html) to replace the single call to `waitpid`:

> "A typical code sequence would be:
>
> ```
>    while((pid = waitpid(,,)) == -1) {
>
>        switch (errno) {
>
>        case EINTR: continue;
>
>        default: printf(stderr, ...)
>
>                break;
>
>        }}
>
>    ... rest of normal waitpid-hanling goes here ...
> ```
>
> Also, you'll probably have to install a signalhandler for at least SIGCHLD . "

Also, I note you have not redirected stderr, which may cause interactions between parent and child.  One other question - did you hit control-C?  If so, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189817/waitpid-not-allowing-sigint-to-be-sent-to-child-process).

Also, `WUNTRACED` may or may not be something you want to specify, depending on whether you're handling terminal signals.  See the manpage for waitpid(2), e.g., [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid).  Perhaps `0`, or `WEXITED`?

Comment: The 1st error is now gone, but the second is still occurring. Not hitting control-C. Even when i use 0 instead WUNTRACED, the parent process still fails to wait.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and while testing: "cat < infile" works fine, when i try to test: "ls -al > outfile" the outfile is still created on my desktop, but contains nothing in it. It remains empty. :-/

Comment: @Gus- try adding `O_WRONLY` to the `open()` call for > file per [this example](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/dup2.html).  If that doesn't help, for a sanity check, what sets the `inpt`, `outpt`, and `outptApp` variables?  `comparator`?  (Note: "The argument flags must include one of the following access modes: O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR." per [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)).

Comment: Bingo! It's always something simple. Thank you very much. I was getting ready to re-write the entire code.